# web api shows 403.14 error when localhost:port number is in browser address in iis express

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

This has to be something really dumb but I can't think what else to do.

Using Visual Studio 2013 - Update 1, I created an empty web api 2 project in an existing solution, added the cross origin support (cors) package and created a basic web api controller.

The WebApiConfig class seems to be fine:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And also the Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

I then run the application, IIS express starts normally and the browser starts with the application's url but nothing seems to work.

If the URL is "localhost:port number" I get  **HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory**.

If I try "localhost:port number/api" I get **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

I have looked at several blogs, tutorials, examples and I haven't seen anywhere that anything special needs to be done. Could someone please shed some light in what I might be missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Web Api doesn't have a default viewable page (aspx, html, etc) that can be viewed by navigating to the root (`localhost:port` in this case).  So that is the normal behavior.  In order to access your Api through the controller you need to access it using the route template specified in your `MapHttpRoute()` method.

So to access the `GET` method in your Api you would open a browser and place `localhost:port/api/{controllername}` into the url.  `{controllername}` would be set to the name of your controller class without Controller added to the end.

ex: If your controller looked like this:

```
public class TestController : ApiController {
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() {
          return something;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id) {
          return something with id;
    } 
}
```

Then your url for the first `Get()` would look like this:

```
localhost:port/api/test
```

And the url for the second `Get(int id)` would look like this:

```
localhost:port/api/test/5
```

Comment: I also tried that and I get the explorer "The website cannot display the page" and as the cause "The website has a programming error"

Comment: Can you post some of your Controller class so we can see what your methods look like?

Comment: Turns out I was trying to use custom names for the methods and then realize that this api only admits the standard http verbs unless the route definition is changed which is not a requirement for me just now. Thanks for taking the time to respond your answer did make me realize this.

Comment: Good.  Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

If yours route config is OK for sure, you can try add this in Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!